# strange behavior with Turkish language setting

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

I have database with Collation Arabic_CI_AS

when I have windows with English settings I can do

```
select Column from Table where Column= 'A'
```

and can do

```
select column from table where column= 'a'
```

I mean the naming is not case sensitive

In Turkish windows

if any of the names not as named in the DB it raise error in my windows application

I mean that in Turkish windows the names must be case sensitive

any idea to explain that and how to solve it such that I don't face it again in any language settings

Comment: Could you try to clarify what you mean by "Turkish windows"?

Answer (score 1):

The difference might be in the collation used.

Depending on the collation, the code might be case sensitive or case insensitive.

You can check server collation with this command:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')
```

Somwtimes, database collation may be different, check it with this command:

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('DatabaseName', 'Collation')
```

---

For more info, see [THIS](http://www.abstraction.net/ViewArticle.aspx?articleID=72) article.

Answer (score 0):

Your using Accent-sensitive (_AS) which may play a role in other languages (like Turkish), it Distinguishes between accented and unaccented characters, do you have accented letters in your Database?

besides you are using Arabic_CI_AS, why not use **Turkish_CI_AS**? the Arabic and Turkey letters are different? the Turkey letters use latein ones too.

Take a look at these links, hope they help you further:

- [Collation Settings in Setup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143508.aspx)
- [Windows Collation Sorting Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143515.aspx)

Comment: What should work? case insensitive search or only if you search english letters? or should the search be allways case sensitive?

Comment: the problem in type the Database table name, A not a

Comment: What are you using for the DB-Connectivity in your windows application? Try with this Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx#Unicode_Defn